# Cannot get Failover Cluster Manager to see Cluster Shared Volume over 5TB

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-server-2012-r2, clustering

I'm not having any luck finding information on how to expand the Cluster Shared Volume in Failover Cluster Manager, so I'm hoping someone here may be able to help me get this resolved. Here's what's going on:

We have Veeam backup on our Hyper-V environment that does backup to a series of cluster shared volumes. Several of the volumes are near capacity, so I allocated more space to each affected volume, then went into DISKPART and extended the volumes out to 7TB from 5TB. The servers that use the shared storage can see the volumes as 7TB, but the Failover Cluster Manager is still only registering the disks at 5TB:

[FCM vs Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN3qv.png)

Disk Manager on the servers that use the resource can also see the full 7TB, but I don't see an option, even in Maintenance Mode, to adjust the size of the volume in Failover Cluster Manager. Can anyone point me at a resource or explain what needs to happen so that FCM can see the full size of the volume? Thank you!

Comment: What is the sector size on this disk? Possibly a larger one will work better.

Comment: Bytes/Sector: 512
Sectors/Track: 63
Size: 7.00 TB (7,696,583,677,440 bytes)
Total Cylinders: 935,723
Total Sectors: 15,032,389,995
Total Tracks: 238,609,365
Tracks/Cylinder: 255
Partition: Disk #3, Partition #0
Partition Size: 7.00 TB (7,696,583,677,440 bytes)

Comment: Like I said, the operating systems aren't having a problem seeing the volumes for what they are. This is just in the Failover Cluster Manager.

Comment: Hyper-V uses 512 byte sectors for VHD, which is ridiculous. You need VHDX for block size of 4096 bytes to match modern large disks.

Answer (score 0):

For all the years I've worked in IT, this is the first time I can remember actually finding a bug, reporting it to Microsoft, and having it confirmed. The issue will be addressed in next month's patches, and I was the lucky one to find it.

## Symptom

On disk 3, the disk has been extended but volume capacity was not reflected.
DISKPART> detail volume

Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt

---

- Disk 3    Reserved       7168 GB      0 B        *

Read-only              : No
Hidden                 : No
No Default Drive Letter: Yes
Shadow Copy            : No
Offline                : No
BitLocker Encrypted    : No
Installable            : Yes

Volume Capacity        : 5119 GB
Volume Free Space      :  128 GB

## Scope

Issue Definition: On disk 3, the disk has been extended but volume capacity was not reflected.
Scope Agreement: This issue is considered to be resolved once disk could be extended properly.

## Action plan

1. Assign some more disk space to the disk the CSV is sitting on .
2. Then, on the CSV Owner Node, extend it with the GUI e.g. disk manager.
3. Both displayed disk sizes and volume capacity values get updated to the correct size.

   ## Resolution

It is confirmed that it is a bug.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3189825/extending-a-csv-by-using-diskpart-or-powershell-is-not-blocked-from-a

But we can work around it by extending it once again in GUI e.g. disk manager.